# Unused use statement with Yii 2 behavior class in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, yii2, namespaces

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Category;
use app\components\NewsBehavior;

class ModelTestController extends Controller
{
```

The class `app\components\NewsBehavior` exists, but Netbeans gives warning:

> Unused use statement (on the line: use app\components\NewsBehavior;).

`NewsBehavior` class can not be use directly since it's behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you defined it, but didn't use it (at least explicitly) within the current class.

If your don't need it in current class, just remove this declaration.

Otherwise if you configuring behaviors `class` like a string (for example: `'class' => 'app\components\NewsBehavior'`, obviously this declared class is not used directly and in the current form this declaration in `use` is redundant.

However there is another way of passing class with static `className()` method:

```
'class' => NewsBehavior::className(),
```

If you will use that, that IDE notice will disappear since now you are explicitly referring to that class.

**Official docs:**

- [yii\base\Object className()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#className%28%29-detail)